# Is it possible to get a list of validated receipt data from iTunes Connect?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, receipt

After my new iOS App was approved last friday, today I recognized that I mistakenly rolled back an SVN change and therefor all In-App-Purchases that were made during the weekend were validated in the wrong place (Sandbox URL). (Error code 21008: This receipt is a production receipt, but it was sent to the sandbox server.)

Now, I can see in iTunes connect that there were a bunch of successful purchases. But the problem is that - since validation failed (due to the wrong URL) - I did not enabled the special features within the App for those users on the server side.

I tried the whole day to find out which of the app's users made a purchase, so that I can enable the extra features that the users paid for now (and to send them my apologize via email).

But since the receipt data is send via POST requests, I was not able to get this info from my server's log files. And in iTunes Connect I was not able to find some report(s) that include the receipt data for successful purchases.

The last option would be to enable the extra features within the app for **all** users who logged in during the weekend. However, I'd prefer to get my hands on the receipt data.

Is that possible at all? Does Apple grant access to this data? Any idea(s)?